# Why would I get an error that an input VMID does not resolve to a single virtual machine?

Tags: powershell

I'm using PowerShell to connect to a Hyper-V virtual machine.  But for some reason when I try to start a PSSession, I get the error "*The input VMID  does not resolve to a single virtual machine.*"

The code looks like this:

```
$HyperVServerName = "TheServerName"
$VMName = "AValidVMName"
$SnapshotName = "ASnapshotName"
$creds = Get-Credential

Restore-VMSnapshot -ComputerName $HyperVServerName -VMName $VMName -Name $SnapshotName -Confirm:$false

Start-VM -ComputerName $HyperVServerName -Name $VMName

#Do some checks to make sure the VM is running...

$VMID = (Get-VM -ComputerName $HyperVServerName -Name $VMName).ID

If(-Not ($VMID -eq $null))
{
    $psSession = New-PSSession -VMId $VMID -Credential $creds
    If(-Not ($psSession -eq $null))
    {
        Enter-PSSession -Session $psSession
        #Do some stuff here...
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error on the line `$psSession = New-PSSession -VMId $VMID -Credential $creds`.

More Information about the error:

- CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument (:) [New-PSSession], ArgumentException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVMIdNotSingle,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSSessionCommand

Any ideas on what's causing this error, and how I can correct it?

---

I was able to run commands on the VM before, but I tried to modify the code so that I didn't have to supply the host name of the VM when using `Invoke-Command`.

Comment: Try using the `VMId` property instead of the `Id` property.

Answer (score 1):

Just a few thoughts here, and not real sure why you are targeting the VMId, but it's a choice.

I am just calling stuff dynamically here to avoid, well, you know...

```
$HyperVServerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$VMName = (Get-VM)[3].Name
$creds = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"

# I am using variable squeezing to assign and output info. In prod you'd remove those parens.
($VMID = (Get-VM -ComputerName $HyperVServerName -Name $VMName).ID)

<#
When it comes to PSRemotig, it's one or the other
- Implicit = New-PSSession - remote command stuff - Invoke-Command, etc...
- Explicit = Enter-PSSssion - user ineractive stuff
they cannot be use on the same target at the same time, it's redundant.

Also, the $VMID would never be not null, becasue you are directly populating it above.
#>

If(-Not ($VMID -eq $null))
{
    <#
    There is going to be an Implicit PSRemoting session when you do this
    You can see this, if you output the info as you call it. Well, in testing.
    I am using variable squeezing to assign and output info. In prod you'd remove those parens.
    #>
    ($psSession = New-PSSession -VMId $VMID -Credential $creds)

    <#
    So this is moot. The session wll never be -Not null, becasue of the previous command,
    Unless the session connection failed, then you should be catching that error anyway.
    so, don't do this Explicit command, if you are directly setting an Implicit one. 
    Even in your code below, it's still moot, as you are trying to use that $pssession
    which does not exist, via the ENter-PSSession.

    So, if $pssession is null, the Enter-PSSEssion is also moot.
    #>

    <#
    If(-Not ($psSession -eq $null))
    {

        Enter-PSSession -Session $psSession
        #Do some stuff here...
    }
    #>

}

# So, you code could be something like.

$HyperVServerName = "TheServerName"
$VMName = "AValidVMName"
$SnapshotName = "ASnapshotName"
$creds = Get-Credential

Restore-VMSnapshot -ComputerName $HyperVServerName -VMName $VMName -Name $SnapshotName -Confirm:$false

Start-VM -ComputerName $HyperVServerName -Name $VMName

#Do some checks to make sure the VM is running...
($VMHost = Get-VM -ComputerName $HyperVServerName -Name $VMName)

Try
{
    ($psSession = New-PSSession -VMId $VMHost.Name -Credential $creds)
    # Do some stuff here
}
Catch
{
    Write-Warning -Message "Error calling the implicit remote session for $($VMHost.Name). Starting explicit session for $($VMHost.Name)."
    $Error | Format-List -Force | Out-String | clip | notepad 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    [void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("system.windows.forms")
    [system.windows.forms.sendkeys]::SendWait('^v')


    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $($VMHost.Name) -Credential $creds
    #Do some stuff here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error for running just `$psSession = New-PSSession -VMId $VMID -Credential $creds` or `$psSession = New-PSSession -VMName $VMNAME -Credential $creds` for any VM. Starting powershell as administrator resolved the error for me.